# Inserting blocks into custom places in Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

In Magento 1

I can edit `local.xml` like so:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="above_main" template="page/html/banner.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

I can edit a template file like so:

```
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

        <?php // MY EDIT: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('above_main');

        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

<!-- rest of page... -->
```

This will end up with the file at `page/html/banner.phtml` being inserted into the template at my own custom position, `above_main`.

OK, so my question is:

How do I do this in Magento 2?

Comment: You can use default.xml to achieve this.

Comment: @amitshree show me how and i will give you a tick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no more local.xml in Magento 2. Magento has instead chosen to have all of the XML within the module. If you want to modify XML for a module, you will have to make a new XML file with the same name in your equivalent theme directory and make the modifications there. 
 
There are many possible ways to insert your template into a particular page.

**Alternative 1** 
Let's assume you want to add a template on product details page. You need to create new xml file `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module. You xml code might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Lapisbard\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra"
               name="product.view.extra"
               template="Lapisbard_Catalog::product/view/extra.phtml"
               after="product.info.overview">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Here I'm inserting a custom template on product page. You can use `before/after` tag to arrange your container according to your need of where you want to place your template. Similar way you can create layout files in your module account to handle of the page. Ex: you can use `cms_index_index.xml` for home page.

**Alternative 2**
You can call your custom template file in any other template file using following code:

```
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Lapisbard\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra')
          ->setTemplate('Lapisbard_Catalog::product/view/extra.phtml')
          ->toHtml();
```

**Alternative 3**
Have a look at this tutorial which highlights how you can utilize default.xml to make structural changes https://gielberkers.com/creating-blocks-in-magento-2/